# Do duplicated emitted events overlap/get called together in a parent component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-events

I have two children components (**CModal1** and **CModal2**) inside a parent component and both of them are wrapper in the **ModalWrapper** component. This wrapper component gives each modal a transition effect and a close event (an X button and a background that both emit the `close` event).
Right now, if the outter most layer's (**Modal2**) `close` buttons are clicked, it also closes **Modal1**. Is this because both `@close` events fire?

How can I remedy this? Should I put the wrapper of **Modal2** inside the actual component, rather than wrapping it in the parent?

If I haven't explained things correctly, or you need more code/context, please let me know.

Cheers!

**ParentComponent**

```
<template>
  <ModalWrapper
    @close="modal1Open = false"
    :isVisible="modal1IsVisible"
  >
    <CModal1
      v-if="modal1IsVisible"
      :formData="formData"
      @close="modal1IsVisible = false"
      @save-data="(val) => saveData(val)"
      @open-modal-2-clicked="modal2Open = true"
    />
  </ModalWrapper>
  <ModalWrapper
    @close="modal2Open = false"
    :isVisible="modal2Open"
    class="z-30"
  >
    <CModal2
      v-if="modal2IsVisible"
      @close="modal2IsVisible = false"
    />
  </ModalWrapper>
</template>
```

Comment: there would anyway be a difference in timing of trigger (delay between two triggers) so there won't be overlapping. They will executed in the same order how they were triggered

Comment: @Amaarrockz Thanks for the reply! So just because the bottom component `@close` event is emitted from **ModalWrapper**, that doesn't mean it will trigger on the top component? I wonder why they both are closing then.

Comment: it depends on from where you emitting the close !